# Activity in android can be compared with which element in ios

Tags: android, ios

I'm new to iOS development can any one help how to compare android with ios application development.

Comment: With a `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0):

activity in android is compared to iOS UIViewController.
In Android activity means single screen or window 
In iOS UIBViewController is single Screen.